# Sum of multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, stimulsoft

I have a report like this

```
ID     Score 1     Score 2     Sum     Average
1        5            5         10        5
2        7            6         13       6.5
3        4            8         12        6
.        .            .          .        .
.        .            .          .        .
.        .            .          .        .
Total    16           19        35       17.5
```

I have `Score 1` and `Score 2`, but I need to get `Sum`, `Average`, and `Total` through Stimulsoft.

How can I use sum for getting summation of two columns in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this Sql query helps:

```
Select CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [ID], Score1, Score2, (Score1 + Score2) AS [SUM], ((Score1 + Score2)/2) AS [AVG] from Yourtable
UNION ALL
Select 'Total', SUM(Score1), SUM(Score2), SUM((Score1 + Score2)), SUM(((Score1 + Score2)/2)) from Yourtable
```

You can also look into [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186241(v=sql.105).aspx) for sum and average columns if its a frequently used query.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one seems to be answering, i'll give this a try. I'm not sure that what you need is an sql query or Stimulsoft consultance. I'll try the former:

```
Select cast(id as varchar(max)), score1, score2, score1+score2 as sum, (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),score1)+score2)/2 as average
from yourtable
UNION ALL
Select 'Total', (select sum(score1) from yourtablename) as Score1Total,(select sum(score2) from yourtablename) as Score2Total, (select sum(score1)+sum(score2) from yourtablename) as TotalSum, (select (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(score1))+sum(score2))/count(*)) from yourtablename as TotalAverage
```

Should return what you posted. However, returning the last row (Total) as part of the query is bad design, to say the least. That should be done in the next step, when you actually display/generate a report file.

Comment: PS1 - if score1 datatype is INT, the average might also be rounded as an INT (no decimal places). Hence, you might need a cast, too - i'll edit my answer in a minute.

Comment: PS2 - this is the first time ever that I cast an id as varchar. Did that to make sure "union all" with the last ('Total') row didn't raise an error. Shouldn't, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should use next expression in text component:
`{Sum(Score1+Score2)}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are all numerics, no null cells,  and not character data try something like this to get column sum, avg and totals:

```
SELECT col1, col2, (col1 + col2) AS thesum, ((col1 + col2)/2) AS theavg FROM sometable;
```

Chain it with another select to get total over rows

```
SELECT sum(col1) as TC1, sum(col2) as TC2, sum(thesum), sum(theavg) from
   (SELECT col1, col2, (col1 + col2) AS theism, ((col1 + col2)/2) AS theavg 
    FROM some table);
```

Note, if you have more than two columns to average, you can just chain selects.